# XPath: Parent form of submit button

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I want to use PHP and `DomXPath::query` to get the parent "form" element of a submit button. The variable `$dom` holds the complete DOM tree and `$node` represents the submit button as a DOM node.

```
$query = '??????';
$xpath = new \DomXPath( $dom );

$parents = $xpath->query( $query, $node );

if ( $parents->length )
{

    $form = $parents->item( 0 );

}
```

I tried several queries, but until now I found no solution. I think it would be easy if I had more time to read about that XPath syntax. I hope you can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = 'ancestor::form';
```

This assumes the submit button only has one ancestor that is a form (you cannot nest forms in HTML).